# How do I rewrite this Firebase function so my returned array isn't empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, return, firebase

I'm working with Firebase and having trouble getting my array to return the Firebase data I'm querying. The array I'm trying to fill is randomly returning empty. What's the most efficient way to do this?

```
const getCityData = function ( ) {
    const dataRef = firebaseRef.child("cities");
    const cities = [];
    let cityItem = null;

    dataRef.orderByChild("name").on("child_added", function ( snapshot ) {
        cityItem = snapshot.val();

        if ( cityItem.name && cityItem.isListable ) {
            cities.push( cityItem );
        }
    });
    return (cities);
};
```

I've edited my code as per some answers but still can't get it, unfortunately. In this one, I can scope into the code in the console and execute it just fine. Other than that, Firebase is not breaking at the .forEach section. Still lost.

```
const getCityDataAndThen = function (callback) {
    const dataRef = firebaseRef.child("cities");
    const cities = [];
    let city = null;

    dataRef.orderByChild("name").once("value", function ( snapshot ) {
        snapshot.forEach(function ( citySnapshot ) {
            city = citySnapshot.val();

            if ( city.name && city.isListable ) {
                cities.push( city );
            }
        });
    });
    callback(cities);
};

 const getCityData = function () {
    getCityDataAndThen(function (cities) {
        return (cities);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning Cities when the data is not yet available. You should return a Promise Object in getCityData instead of any array. And use promise.then when the data is available.

Something like this..

```
function GetById(id) {
        var child =  ref.child("users").child(id);
        var fireObj =  $firebaseObject(child);



            return fireObj;

        }
```

Now once you get fireObj use it like.

Then will invoke when the data is available.

```
fireObject.then(function(){

});
```

Comment: Thanks, promises make sense. I'm trying to figure out the best way to incorporate that into my code.

Comment: In your post above why are you using fireObject and fireObj? I'm super confused right now.

Comment: I am using angularfire which provides $firebaseObject and $firebaseArray for referring to nodes of firebase. I am returning that as a variable. Does it clarifies?

Answer (score 0):

As sushil said, you cannot return data that hasn't loaded yet.

Your solutions are to either:

1. pass in a callback function that will be invoked when the data has loaded
2. return a promise that will be resolved when the data has loaded

I'm going to stick to option 1 here.

```
const getCityDataAndThen = function (callback) {
  const dataRef = firebaseRef.child("cities");
  const cities = [];
  let cityItem = null;

  dataRef.orderByChild("name").once("value", function ( snapshot ) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(citySnapshot) {
      citySnapshot = snapshot.val();

      if ( cityItem.name && cityItem.isListable ) {
        cities.push( cityItem );
      }
    });
  });
  callback (cities);
};
```

You can now invoke this as:

```
getCityDataAndThen(function(cities) {
  console.log(cities);
});
```

You'll notice that I switched to using `once('value'`, because with `on('child_added'` you have no clear moment when you're done getting the children.

Comment: Hmm this seems like it would work but I'm not having any success. In your example here `citySnapshot` is returning null. Not sure why just yet.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect closer to what you've posted here and it looks like Firebase is not returning the snapshot properly. Not sure if you have any other ideas.